# Make array of array elements that pairs my data to the index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array [10, 67, 44, 55] how can I turn this into [[1, 10], [2, 67], [3, 44], [4, 55]] ?

I need to make a linear regression line and need to feed my data as an array of array elements like this:

linearRegression([[1, 10], [2, 67], [3, 44], [4, 55], ..., [n, k]]); where n is just the index + 1 that I am using as the x-value and k is my y-value. Using a for loop and array.push I made an array of all of my y data points (not const, from json file).

How can I turn [10, 67, 44, 55] into [[1, 10], [2, 67], [3, 44], [4, 55]] ? Please note that I can't do this manually as n will change as my data query returns more or less data value k's.

I am new to javascript so please excuse my use of array.push as I know that there may be a better way to use the map function for ES6 but that's still a bit more confusing to me- but I'm willing to learn! Thank you!

Comment: there should be some fucntion like zip with index i am not sure.

Comment: yep, that's ```.map((item, index) => {/*whatever*/})```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map`, this situation is exactly what it's designed for:

```js
const input = [10, 67, 44, 55];
const output = input.map((num, i) => [i + 1, num]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me [[10, 1],  [67, 2], [44, 3], [55, 4]] and I need [[1, 10], [2, 67], [3, 44], [4, 55]]  to get the correct values for the linear regression function.

Comment: I don't think it does? Press "Run code snippet", it should say `[
  [
    1,
    10
  ],
  [
    2,
    67
  ],
  [
    3,
    44
  ],
  [
    4,
    55
  ]
]`, isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: That's odd. When I copy and paste it into my code it gives me [[10, 1], [67, 2], [44, 3], [55, 4]]

Comment: You copied `input.map((num, i) => [i + 1, num]);` ? If it gives you `[[10, 1]...` then your browser's interpreter sounds broken...

Comment: I think this is an issue with something I'm doing, not your snippet. I'll keep tinkering to see what's going on and will report back, but you're right, your snippet does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**DEMO**

```js
let arr = [10, 67, 44, 55];

console.log(arr.map((v,i)=>[i+1,v]));
```